# prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/bison/bison: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Tags: bison

I'm trying to compile android8.1 on ubuntu16.04,
but I get the error "prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/bison/bison: Syntax error: "(" unexpected".

ubuntu16.04 is based on 'ubuntu on windows'.

Help me,please

log:
No need to regenerate ninja file
[  0% 1/364] //system/tools/hidl:libhidl-gen-ast yacc hidl-gen_y.yy [linux]
FAILED: out/soong/.intermediates/system/tools/hidl/libhidl-gen-ast/linux_x86_64_shared/gen/yacc/system/tools/hidl/hidl-gen_y.cpp out/soong/.intermediates/system/tools/hidl/libhidl-gen-ast/linux_x86_64_shared/gen/yacc/system/tools/hidl/hidl-gen_y.h
BISON_PKGDATADIR=external/bison/data prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/bison/bison -d  --defines=out/soong/.intermediates/system/tools/hidl/libhidl-gen-ast/linux_x86_64_shared/gen/yacc/system/tools/hidl/hidl-gen_y.h -o out/soong/.intermediates/system/tools/hidl/libhidl-gen-ast/linux_x86_64_shared/gen/yacc/system/tools/hidl/hidl-gen_y.cpp system/tools/hidl/hidl-gen_y.yy
prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/bison/bison: 1: prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/bison/bison: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
[  1% 6/364] //external/boringssl:libcrypto clang src/crypto/cipher_extra/e_aesgcmsiv.c [linux]
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
09:44:20 ninja failed with: exit status 1

Answer (score 0):

[WSL doesn't support 32-bit i386 ELF binaries](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/390) for now, you can get the details in [github WSL #1687](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1687)